# Redirect stdout to a text widget

Tags: python

I have searched and found some answers on redirecting the sys.stdout to a text widget in python, but I can't apply them to my specific needs.

I have coded a simple GUI with tkinter for a downloader found [here](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2010/10/04/rsapiget-download-rapidshare-api)  and I want the stdout messages to appear on a text widget, which after much effort I couldn't achieve.

So let's make my case clearer with my code:

```
from Tkinter import*
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import urllib2
import sys


#functions
def downloadlinks():

# Configuration BEGIN
    LOGIN = ''
    PASSWORD = ''
    USE_SSL = False
    VERIFY_MD5SUM = False
# Configuration END


    __version__ = '0.1.0'

    import sys
    import os
    import urllib
    import subprocess
    import time
    try:
        import hashlib
        md5 = hashlib.md5
    except ImportError:
        import md5
        md5 = md5.new

    def info(msg):
        sys.stdout.write('\n%s\n\n' % msg)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def error(msg):
        sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % msg)
        sys.stderr.flush()
        sys.exit(1)

    def transfer_progress(blocks_transfered, block_size, file_size):
        percent = float((blocks_transfered * block_size * 100) / file_size)
        progress = float(blocks_transfered * block_size / 1024)
        downspeed = (float(blocks_transfered * block_size) / float(time.time() - starttime)) / 1024
        sys.stdout.write("Complete: %.0f%% - Downloaded: %.2fKb - Speed: %.3fkb/s\r" % (percent, progress, downspeed))
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def download(source, target):
        global starttime
        starttime = time.time()
        filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(source, target, transfer_progress)
        sys.stdout.write('Complete: 100%\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        for ss in headers:
            if ss.lower() == "content-disposition":
                filename = headers[ss][headers[ss].find("filename=") + 9:]  # 9 is len("filename=")=9
        urllib.urlcleanup()     # Clear the cache
        return filename

    def verify_file(remote_md5sum, filename):
        f = open(filename, "rb")
        m = md5()
        while True:
            block = f.read(32384)
            if not block:
                break
            m.update(block)
        md5sum = m.hexdigest()
        f.close()
        return md5sum == remote_md5sum

    def main():

        file_link = "https://rapidshare.com/files/33392/examplefile.rar"

        info('Downloading: %s' % file_link.split("/")[5])

        try:
            rapidshare_com, files, fileid, filename = file_link.rsplit('/')[-4:]
        except ValueError:
            error('Invalid Rapidshare link')
        if not rapidshare_com.endswith('rapidshare.com') or files != 'files':
            error('Invalid Rapidshare link')

        if USE_SSL:
            proto = 'https'
            info('SSL is enabled00000000000')

        else:
            proto = 'http'

        if VERIFY_MD5SUM:
            info('MD5 sum verification is enabled')

        info('Downloading: %s' % file_link.split("/")[5])


        if filename.endswith('.html'):
            target_filename = filename[:-5]
        else:
            target_filename = filename
        info('Save file as: %s' % target_filename)


    # API parameters

        params = {
        'sub': 'download_v1',
        'fileid': fileid,
        'filename': filename,
        'try': '1',
        'withmd5hex': '0',
        }

        if VERIFY_MD5SUM:
            params.update({
                'withmd5hex': '1',
                })

        if LOGIN and PASSWORD:
            params.update({
                'login': LOGIN,
                'password': PASSWORD,
                })

        params_string = urllib.urlencode(params)

        api_url = '%s://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi' % proto

# Get the first error response
        conn = urllib.urlopen('%s?%s' % (api_url, params_string))
        data = conn.read()
#print data
        conn.close()

# Parse response
        try:
            key, value = data.split(':')
        except ValueError:
            error(data)
        try:
            server, dlauth, countdown, remote_md5sum = value.split(',')
        except ValueError:
            error(data)

# Wait for n seconds (free accounts only)
        if int(countdown):
            for t in range(int(countdown), 0, -1):
                sys.stdout.write('Waiting for %s seconds...\r' % t)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(1)
            info('Waited for %s seconds. Proceeding with file download...' % countdown)

    # API parameters for file download

        dl_params = {
            'sub': 'download_v1',
            'fileid': fileid,
            'filename': filename,
            }

        if LOGIN and PASSWORD:
            dl_params.update({
                'login': LOGIN,
                'password': PASSWORD,
                })
        else:
            dl_params.update({
                'dlauth': dlauth,
                })

        dl_params_string = urllib.urlencode(dl_params)

        download_link = '%s://%s/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?%s' % (proto, server, dl_params_string)

        downloaded_filename = download(download_link, target_filename)

        if VERIFY_MD5SUM:
            if remote_md5sum.lower() == 'not found':
                info('Remote MD5 sum is not available. Skipping MD5 sum verification...')
            elif downloaded_filename:
                if verify_file(remote_md5sum.lower(), downloaded_filename):
                    info('Downloaded and verified %s' % downloaded_filename)
                else:
                    error('The downloaded file could not be verified')
            else:
                error('Will not verify. File not found: %s' % downloaded_filename)

        info('Operation Complete')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            error('\nAborted')

    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Download Status Notification',"All files have been downloaded.")







#Window Title    
app=Tk()
app.title("Downloader")
app.geometry('700x1080+550+0')
app.resizable(0,0)


#Title    
titleText = StringVar()
titleText.set("Downloader")
label0=Label(app,textvariable=titleText,font=("Times", 16,"bold"),height=2)
label0.pack()

#


f1 = Frame(app, width=600, height=200)
xf1 = Frame(f1, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=5)

#Text
labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set("Enter link:")
label1=Label(f1,textvariable=labelText,font=("Times", 14))
label1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5,pady=8)


#Field
linkname = StringVar(None)
linkname1 =Entry(f1,textvariable = linkname,font=("Times", 14),justify=CENTER)
linkname1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5,pady=8)
Label(f1, text='').place(relx=1.06, rely=0.125,anchor=CENTER)
f1.pack()


#Button
downloadbutton=Button(app,text="Download",font=("Times", 12, "bold"),width=20,borderwidth=5,foreground = 'white',background = 'blue',command=downloadlinks)
downloadbutton.pack()

#####
downloadmessages = Text(app,height = 6,width=80,font=("Times", 12),foreground = 'cyan',background='black' )
downloadmessages.insert(END,"")
downloadmessages.pack(padx=20,pady=1)

app.mainloop()
```

---

So,let me ask some questions.My code descriptively is like that :

-import modules

-def downloadlinks()

-Window Title

-Title

-Frame with :
      Text
      Field

-Button

-Text Widget

When it says `my_frame = your_gui_code_here()`, does it refer to the Text Widget Code ?

```
downloadmessages = Text(app,height = 6,width=80,font=("Times", 12),foreground = 'cyan', background='black' )
downloadmessages.insert(END,"")
downloadmessages.pack(padx=20,pady=1)
```

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to open it as a subprocess and then pipe the stdout from there to a writeable source.

e.g.

```
import subprocess
my_frame = your_gui_code_here()
process = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
my_frame.add_text(process.communicate()[0]) #or however you add text.
```

Comment: Can you make it more specific to my case to understand it better ?

Comment: @Jakob he doesn't want the stdout of an external program to go to his app text area, but the stdout of his app itself. Did you look at his code?

Comment: @everybody I am just starting on python,so I am making lots of questions.Sorry if some of them have obvious answers.

Comment: Its fine its just not hard to adjust this using the docs to meet your criteria.